# How to find the value that occurs the most amount of times in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If you had a dictionary with multiple keys and values how would you find which value occurs the most within that dictionary. I'm very new to coding so **I don't want to import anything**. I'm thinking maybe creating an empty list, reading through the dictionary with some for loops, then starting a count and appending the item that occurs the most into this list. Would this be possible? The simpler I can keep it the better

Sample Data:

```
dict = {'Bob': ['Paul', 'Mark', 'Carol', 'Leanne', 'Will'], 'Carol': ['Mark', 'Leanne'], 'Farley': ['Paul'], 'Leanne': ['Sarai'], 'Larry': ['Carol', 'Mark', 'Leanne', 'Will'], 'Mark': ['Philip', 'Zach'], 'Paul': ['Zach'], 'Will': ['Leanne', 'Mark'], 'Zach': ['Philip']}
```

Comment: your idea sounds possible. One hint - you can do `list(my_dict.values())` to automatically get a list of all the values, so you don't have to read through it yourself. Feel free to post what you've tried / what doesn't work and then people will be better able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use collections package, create a function to populate the dictionary

```
c = {}

In [23]: for k,v in dict1.items(): 
    ...:     for elem in v: 
    ...:         if elem not in c: 
    ...:             c[elem]=1 
    ...:         else: 
    ...:             c[elem]+=1 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                          

In [24]:                                                                                                                                                                          

In [24]: c                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[24]: 
{'Paul': 2,
 'Mark': 4,
 'Carol': 2,
 'Leanne': 4,
 'Will': 2,
 'Sarai': 1,
 'Philip': 2,
 'Zach': 2}
```

In case of multiple keys having max value

```
maxVal =0

In [44]: for v in c.values(): 
    ...:     if v > maxVal: 
    ...:         maxVal = v 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                          

In [45]: maxVal                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[45]: 4                                                                                                                         

In [31]: keys= []


In [34]: for k,v in c.items(): 
    ...:     if v == maxVal: 
    ...:         keys.append(k) 
    ...:          
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                          


In [36]: print(*keys,sep=',')                                                                                                                                                     
Mark,Leanne
```

Comment: updated the answer to find max with using collections module

Comment: what did you not understand. its basically a two-step process. 1- create a dictionary containing the values as key and total no of occurrence as its value. once you have dictionary use the max function to get key having the greatest value

Comment: please share sample input data. I guess you dictionary contains list as values

Comment: since the values of are dictionary are list, you need to iterate thought the elem of the list to create the dictionary. Updated my answer.

Comment: I have added an answer using for loop but you can do it using the operator module in a single line.

Comment: you mean the max function part or the for loop ?

Comment: use a for loop to find the maxValue by comparing each value. Updated the answer

Comment: please care to accept/upvote the answer if it works for you

Comment: use the both sets of the code. Have remove the part not required by you